# Changing name attribute when cloned in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form like so

```
<tr id='actionRow'>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='actionInput[0][action]' id="actionInput"  placeholder='Action' class="form-control"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='actionInput[0][deliveryDate]' id="dateInput" placeholder='Completion Date' class="form-control dateControl"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can see that the name of my inputs are a 2D array.  I give the users the option to add another row to the table, and this will clone the above.  At the moment, my code for this is like so

```
$("table tr").eq(1).clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').attr('id', 'actionRow'+i);
    $(this).attr({
        'id': function(_, id) {
            return id + i
        },
        'name': function(_, id) {
            return  $(this).attr('name').replace('['+(id-1)+']', '['+id+']')
        },
        'value': ''
    });

    if ($(this).hasClass('dateControl')) {
        $(this).val("");
    }

}).end().appendTo("table");
```

I am having a problem updating the name attribute of the cloned item. For the first cloned row, the html should basically look like the following

```
<tr id='actionRow'>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='actionInput[1][action]' id="actionInput1"  placeholder='Action' class="form-control"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='actionInput[1][deliveryDate]' id="dateInput1" placeholder='Completion Date' class="form-control dateControl"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So the array element becomes 1.  The next cloned row will have 2 etc.

With the JQuery code I have provided, why does the replace not do this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming 'i' exists in the .each function but not providing it as a parameter:

```
.each(function(i, elem){
....code
})
```

....also, when you're doing the replace, the names will all be the same.  it seems like you shouldn't be replacing "[" + (id-1) + "]" but simply: "[0]".

(Sorry, I was on a phone -- here's the full response) The primary issue is that the each(...) loop confuses the idx of the tr with the idx of the input (further, there's no guarantee that the idx of the cloned row will always be one less than the new cloned row).  You need a nested loop that relies on the number of rows in the table rather than the index of the cloned row.

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bzLeraz/

```
$("table tr").eq(0).clone().each(function(tr_idx, tr_elem) {

    var 
      $tr = $(tr_elem),
      newRowIdx = $("table tr").length;

    $tr.attr('id', 'actionRow' + newRowIdx);

    $tr.find("input").each(function(i_idx, i_elem) {

      var $input = $(i_elem);

      $input.attr({
          'id': function(_, id) {
              return id + newRowIdx;
          },
          'name': function(_, id) {
              return id.replace('[0]', '['+ newRowIdx +']');
          },
          'value': ''
      });

      if ($input.hasClass('dateControl')) {
          $input.val("");
      }

    });

  }).appendTo("table");
```

Comment: Sorry, had to pop out.  Why does this not work when I do it using a button? https://jsfiddle.net/fqugd7vL/11/

Comment: Hi Nick, updated this guys fiddle to show usage with button.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/5bzLeraz/2/

Comment: @NickPrice - the find(...) on the tr only looks for input elements, you would need to add other types: .find("input,select,button") -- something like that.

Comment: @NickPrice - sorry, I misunderstood the question see JF's jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks, managed to solve it in the end.  One thing I couldnt work out was the delete button.  How can I handle this without the i variable?